# Music at Seduas Achashverosh

Tags: megillat-esther, music, meal-seudah

Why was there no music at the Meal which Acshverosh made?

Comment: How do you know there wasn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rabbi Matisyahu Solomon asks Why didn’t Achashveirosh provide music to tempt the sense of hearing? He answers based on the Radak who says that we’ll never totally understand Tehilim until we understand the musical instructions and instruments assigned to each piece. The power of a nigun is to add “hesber v’havana b’dakus hadevarim.” To this point, the Meiri explains the pasuk of “Zamru maskil”; that singing gives insight. However, it only gives insight, or is Meorer that which is hidden in our hearts and souls. rather the tune is Meorer what’s in one's heart. Even if a given tune is Meorer some to Ta’avah, nevertheless, the same tune can bring an Ish Kodesh to Dveykus.

Comment: Wow someone told me he said I told him Maybe he meant Reb Calerbach said that Teretz

Answer (score 4):

Different People different tastes- Meam Loez

http://asimplejew.blogspot.com/2008/03/missing-sense-achashverosh-music.html

Comment: Did they not know of headphones? :)

Answer (score 3):

the Manos levi (see Manos HaLevi 1:8. ed Targum Simcha) on Megilas Esther says that Achashveorosh was afraid the Jews would hear music which would remind them of what their souls heard before they came into the world as they heard the singing of the melachim  in shamiyim before coming into this world and the music would  inspire and spiritualy wake them and they would have been distracted from the party

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Sam! Thanks for the answer. You could improve it by editing in where in Manot HaLevi he says this.

Answer (score 1):

The Mahral says the fact that Music is not mentioned does not mean there was non he says the reason it is not mentioned is that Music is something that is not so expensive so the Gemara does not feel the need to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The Targum Simcha notes that it's brought in the sefer Pirsumei Nissa page 79 on the bottom, that the author gives his own explanation. That since it was the minhag yisroel not to listen to music after the churban, Achashverosh did not want to introduce an element to his party that may alienate some attendees, and by playing music it may remind people of the galus they were in and they would not attend.